# Cannot import a module in Python

Tags: python

I have a following problem. I would like to import a module. My folder contains files `A.py` and `B.py`.
In `A.py` I tried:

```
from . import B
```

and

```
import B
```

but I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'
```

File structure:

```
A
├── A.py
├── B.py
└── __init__.py
```

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: How (and from where) are you running `A.py`.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I just open A.py in VS Code and run it by shift+C

Comment: Could you share your file structure? What commands is VS Code actually executing when you are running the file? The information you provide here is not enough, import errors can be caused by a varieaty of reasons.

Comment: please share your file structure

Comment: I have added the file structure in my question above. The folder is named A and contains files A.py, B.py and empty file __init__.py

Comment: Still, how are you executing the file `A.py`? I mean the exact command that your editor is using.

Comment: @Countour-Integral I write into the terminal in VS Code import B, or from . import B

Comment: So you are executing it in the interactive shell?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I am not sure, what you are asking about, sorry. But I can choose from two options in the terminal: 1: powershell and 2: Python. I use 2: Python. Is it what you ask about?

Comment: Perhaps you could post a screenshot here in the comments for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was surprisingly easy - I need to change my current working directory:

```
import os
os.chdir('path to A')
import B
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should call everything from the B file, or a specific class, like this:

```
from B import *
```

Comment: This is not valid python.

Comment: Why not? Shouldn't he import the specific class he wants from that file? Or if he wants everything it is with a '*' notation?

Comment: I have corrected it already @Countour-Integral

Comment: Where `import B` fails, `from B import ...` will also fail.